# update table based on another tables value in sqLite

Tags: join, sqlite, sql-update

We have two tables table1 table2

```
In table1

Itemnumber    SalesCode
123            213UB
142            132NB
1458           256GD

In table2
Itemnumber    ProductGroupCode
123            
142           
1458
```

After Update table2 We need Like this

```
 Itemnumber    ProductGroupCode
    123            213UB
    142            132NB
    1458           256GD
```

We tried like this

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE  table2 JOIN  table1 ON (table2.ItemNumber=table1.ItemNumber) SET table2.CustomerPriceGroup = table1.SalesCode');
```

But We got error like this

```
Colud not prepare Statement (Near "JOIN ":syntax error)
```

Please tell me what wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support [JOINs](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) in UPDATE statements.

You can reach the same result using sub-query like the following

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.CustomerPriceGroup = 
(SELECT table1.SalesCode FROM table1 WHERE table2.ItemNumber=table1.ItemNumber)
```